# sklearn SGDClassifier can't stop

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using `sklearn` to train a model. The train `dataset` is about `3000k`, so i use `SGDClassifier`. The feature is not very good, so i know it may not converge. But i want `SGDClassifier` to stop early according to my setting just like `max_iter = 1000`. As far as I am concerned, the function `SGDClassifier` has no parameter like `max_iter`. How can i do it?
This is the code.
[image]

This is the print information.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: The default interations for SGDClassifier is 5, controlled by `n_iter` param. How long does your model run for?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please [post text, not screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3005167). You may also want to read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: It has been running for about 20 hours.

Comment: How can i stop it and get the current model? So that i can save the model and continue training it later by load the saved model.

Comment: @chenzhixing I posted in my answer a link that shows how to save/load an trained model in sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, by default in scikit-learn 0.18.2, `n_iter` is set to 5 epochs. Can you please update your question with a script that makes it possible to reproduce the behavior using a toy dataset (for instance generated with `numpy.random.randn` or similar).

Note that in scikit-learn master and 0.19 once released, `n_iter` will be deprecated and replaced by `max_iter` and a `tol` (for instance set to 1e-3) to automatically stop when the objective function is no longer making progress.

Answer (score 0):

The 20hours running could be not so strange since you have a dataset of 3000k and you use `SGDClassifier` that is slow. What processor do you have?

Try stopping it by using CTRL+C if you are in Windows. Then, use `n_iter`  to control the number of iterations that you want. The default is 5 however.

Finally, if you want to save a model see here:

[Save and Load Machine Learning Models in Python with scikit-learn](http://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/)